# How to setup a publicly accessible read-only database of emails?

Tags: database, email, self-hosted, web-server, mailing-list

I have been part of an email group for many years and have ~20 GB of emails on it.

I want to setup a new / independent system where I can load all the emails I received as part of that group. However, this system should also be readable to other people, if they have the appropriate credentials.

This database system should be searchable, but there is no need for any mechanism to forward those emails or reply to anyone.

So basically it should serve as a searchable database. Currently that email account is on Google, but I can export it to mbox and then import it into this system.

Ideally people should be able to see threaded conversations - but that's a stretch goal and might be hard for a database to do.

I can self-host this, but would need a mechanism to allow paid access to it.

Alternatively, if there is an inexpensive third-party solution to host this database and allow paid access, that would be great.